Bottom Sheet updates only when i scroll slightly
I have a modalBottomSheet as below.
The Screen inside the modalBottomSheet only updates UI changes when i drag the bottomSheet slightly.
The screen inside bottomSheet is a statless Widget.
I want to update the border color of image inside BottomSheet screen whenever an image is selected. (build image is used to build list of images, dont want to mess the question with lot of unwanted code)
onPressed: () {
                          showModalBottomSheet(
                            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius
                                  .zero, // Set all corner radii to 0
                            ),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.black12,
                            isDismissible: true,
                            enableDrag: true,
                            scrollControlDisabledMaxHeightRatio: 0.7,
                            showDragHandle: false,
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return StatefulBuilder(builder:
                                  (BuildContext context,
                                      StateSetter setmyState) {
                                return ClipRRect(
                                  child: BackdropFilter(
                                    filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                                      sigmaX: 20.0,
                                      sigmaY: 20.0,
                                    ),
                                    child: ThemeScreen(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              });
                            },
                          );
                          HapticFeedback.heavyImpact();
                        },

Below is the widget that changes UI inside bottom sheet screen.
Widget _buildImage(ImageData image) {
  return GetBuilder<HomePageViewModel>(
    builder: (viewModel) {
      final bool isSelected = viewModel.selectedBG.value == image; // Check if the current image is selected

      return CupertinoButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        onPressed: () {
          viewModel.selectedBG(image);
          print('isSelected: $isSelected');
        },
        child: Container(
          width: 120,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, top: 10, right: 8),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: isSelected ? Colors.blue : Colors.transparent, // Change border color based on selection
              width: 2, // Adjust border width as needed
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0), // Adjust as desired
              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                filterQuality: FilterQuality.low,
                imageUrl: "http://contentapp.unice.in${image.image}",
                placeholder: (context, url) => Container(),
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Container(),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}

